# How to fix and toggle bootstrap sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two problems with my current site navigation, using bootstrap. Firstly, I would like to have the sidebar collapsed by default on small and large screen. However, when adding "toggled", it works on large screen but not on mobile.
My second problem is that when i'm on the mobile version, the sidebar (once opened) is not fixed anymore. So the whole page become bigger and you can scroll from left to right.
Any advice would be much appreciated. I have attached my html and css codes.

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -15rem;
  -webkit-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  transition: margin .25s ease-out;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
  padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
  width: 15rem;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  min-width: 100vw;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  #page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -15rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Name</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-KA6wR/X5RY4zFAHpv/CnoG2UW1uogYfdnP67Uv7eULvTveboZJg0qUpmJZb5VqzN" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="d-flex toggled" id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="bg-light" id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar-heading">Logo</div>
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">The Economic Machine</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Finance and Economics</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Politics and Economics</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">IR</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Profile</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">About</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-primary">
   
     <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
    
         <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><span class="clearfix d-none d-sm-inline-block">&nbsp;Home</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="register.html"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i><span class="clearfix d-none d-sm-inline-block">&nbsp;Sign up</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="login.html"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i><span class="clearfix d-none d-sm-inline-block">&nbsp;Login</span></a>
     </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="mt-4">Welcome!</h1>
        <p>The website will soon be available.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Footer -->
  <footer id="sticky-footer" class="py-2 bg-dark text-white-50">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <small> &copy; 2019</small>
    </div>
  </footer>
<!-- Footer --> 
  
  
  
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>

  <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You didn't set `position:fixed`. Instead of using margin to toggle sidebar maybe it would be better to use `left:-15rem`?

Comment: I found [this pretty helpful](https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar) for sidebar menus in bootstrap